# Matlab - Append a new Column to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm a noob in the world of Matlab and I want to append a single value in the beginning of all rows in a matrix.

```
mat =

16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1

myval = 98;
```

I want  to get a matrix like:

```
mat =

98   16     2     3    13
98    5    11    10     8
98    9     7     6    12
98    4    14    15     1
```

What should I do?

I know that we can use horizontal concatenation like `[a b]` but here `myval` and `mat` are not of the same dimension

I did this like:

```
m  = ones(4,1)*98

m =

98
98
98
98

mat = [m mat]

 mat =

98    16     2     3    13
98     5    11    10     8
98     9     7     6    12
98     4    14    15     1
```

Is there a better way ?

Thank you

Comment: The method you're using is totally valid; note however that you needn't assign the new column to a parameter of its own `m` (unless you want to re-use it); `mat = [ones(4,1)*98 mat]` works just as well. Another alternative is to use `repmat`, namely `mat = [repmat(98,4,1) mat]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anothe one-line solution could be:

```
mat=[repmat(myval,size(mat,1),1) mat]
```

By using `size(mat,1)` you can handle automatically the number of rows.

hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks for the Generic answer @il_raffa

Answer (score 1):

I think what you did is fine.  You can one-line it by combining the statements:

```
mat = [(myval*ones(4,1)) mat];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transpose (`'`) with horizontal concatenation (`horzcat` or `[x y]`) as:

```
>> z = magic(4)
z =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
>> c = [98 98 98 98]
c =
    98    98    98    98
>> [c' z]
ans =
    98    16     2     3    13
    98     5    11    10     8
    98     9     7     6    12
    98     4    14    15     1
>> horzcat(c', z)
ans =
    98    16     2     3    13
    98     5    11    10     8
    98     9     7     6    12
    98     4    14    15     1
```